# WPF Datagrid- auto refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid that displays a table which is bound to a SQL server DB.
I would like to set a Timer for every 60 sec, that checks for any update and then displays the latest updated data.

So far I have created an event_handler for datagrid, that includes the object dispatcher timer

```
private void dataGrid1_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

Now I don't know how to proceed further with the event handler to handle the newly updated data from the database.

```
dispatcherTimer_Tick
```

Here is my select statement that is used to fill the datagrid.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String selectstatement = "select top 2 ItemID, ItemName,ConsumerName, Street, DOJ from ConsumarTB order by ItemID ";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectstatement, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

     }
     catch (SqlException e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to improve what you have above.  But here's what I would try for starters.

Below will populate your datagrid on page load, set a timer to tick every 60 seconds.  When the timer ticks, it will call a method to load data to the grid again.

```
//On PageLoad, populate the grid, and set a timer to repeat ever 60 seconds
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RebindData();
        SetTimer();
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

//Refreshes grid data on timer tick
protected void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RebindData();
}

//Get data and bind to the grid
private void RebindData()
{
    String selectstatement = "select top 2 ItemID, ItemName,ConsumerName, Street, DOJ from ConsumarTB order by ItemID ";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectstatement, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}

//Set and start the timer
private void SetTimer()
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: nice illustration for a beginner. thank you. let me try and get back to you.

Comment: will be a good idea to achieve this by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to look into `ObservableCollection<T>` as well as `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  If you create a custom class and bind your grid to an `ObservableCollection<MyCustomClass>`, you shouldn't need to rebind on your updates.  I highly suggest you do it just for the wpf educational benefit. :)

Comment: @JefferyKhan : hello Jeffery, how to achieve this auto refresh the datagrid items using the INotifypropertyChanged ? I have tried displaying a datagrid (using the MVVM way) from a sqlserver, and it was a success, but when my datasource changes , it is not reflected in my UI. Is it possible for u to post another solutin using INotifypropertyChanged with ObservableCollection